# How to pass data through PendingIntent to Broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I'm developing alert app which shows notification and custom message in separate activity when alarm is set off.I'm facing problem in sending identifier to broadcast receiver which is useful in fetching data from database.
I have gone through various blogs, stackoverflow posts but couldn't find the working solution.Please do help me.

My function for scheduling alarm.

```
void setAlarm(int tag, long time) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("TEST", "dummy");
        myIntent.putExtra("ID",tag);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, tag, myIntent, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
    }
```

My Broadcast receiver

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        logHelper.printLog("Alarm Service "+intent.getIntExtra("ID",0)+ intent.getStringExtra("TEST"));
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                AlarmService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
```

Kindly let me know if any further information needed.

Comment: What is the log message that you get from onReceive()?

Comment: Null values in log

Comment: Try replacing Intent.FILL_IN_DATA with 0 while creating pending intent

Comment: Please try to change Intent.FILL_IN_DATA  To  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Comment: I have already tried that.

Comment: what `tag` are you passing to `setAlarm` method? is it always the same `tag`?

Comment: Different everytime , it is integer. Stored in db as primary key.

Comment: ok, so what do you receive in `onReceive` method?

Comment: Null and zero which are default values

Comment: even with 0 `int flags`?

Comment: Yes , even with zero as flag

Comment: Guys , my problem is solved for now . Im sending data in intent.setdata() uri as input.

Comment: can you post your answer

Comment: @SriMaharshiManchem please post your answer

Comment: @GowthamanM at pendingIntent we need to setData like below :     Intent clickIntent = new Intent(this, Receiver.class);
        clickIntent.setData(Uri.parse("textview"));     while retrieving at onReceive method use intent.getData().toString()